# Recommend a good online video host?

Tags: video, streaming

I have been using Vimeo for a good long while to host our corporate videos. I like the service, and it is certainly affordable, but I am quickly outgrowing it. I now have almost 200 videos warehoused in there, most of which I can't get rid of. Plus, Vimeo is just so weak when it comes to management. Finding the right video can be sometimes like finding a needle in a haystack, even with decent metatags. I have been looking at Brightcove and they seem pretty decent, if very expensive for my needs. Can you recommend someone?

Comment: This is off-topic on this site, I believe. You might find [AlternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/software/vimeo/?platform=online) a useful resource.

Comment: @NReilingh - I think it is probably on topic.  Broadcast/content distribution is a portion of audio/video production and streaming is a form of content distribution, so I'd vote it as on-topic.  I do not however have any suggestions because I've always just rolled my own.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how often the videos are watched and how big are they in total?  Rolling your own might work.  For my video streaming needs, I use a dedicated Windows server in a data center (can be as cheap as $110 a month, including a terabyte of disk space and unmetered 100Mb/sec connectivity) and use the included Windows Media Streaming Services to provide streaming video.  Alternately, if you need more cross platform support, there are other stream server software packages you can buy that will allow easy management and streaming of other videos and you can install them on the server.  If your volume of viewers is sufficiently low (less than 20 or 30 simultaneous viewers) then rolling your own may work on a 100 megabit dedicated connection.